# Laravel 5.1 - BelongsTo relationship returns null

Tags: php, oop, laravel, eloquent, relationship

**\App\User**

```
class User

public function status() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserStatus', 'user_status_id', 'id');
}
```

**\App\UserStatus**

```
class UserStatus

protected $fillable = ['id'];

public function user() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'user_status_id', 'id');
}
```

I already have the `$user` object from a simple `User::find()` query with some fields, then I try to access the `status` object by lazy loading it with `$user->load('status')` method.

I'm following the docs, but it seems useless since `$user->status` still returns null.

```
public function foo(User $user) {

    $user->load('status');
    $user->status // returns null
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**--------- SOLUTION ---------**

Actually, to lazy load any relationship, the foreign key value needs to be stored in the model object.

In my `find` operation, I wasn't querying the `user_status_id` field. When I added this field into the query, the `$user->status` statement started to return the `UserStatus` model.

I don't think this information is written on the Laravel docs, it may be simple, but it took me some time to figure that out.

Comment: "Actually, to lazy load any relationship, the foreign key value needs to be stored in the model object." Well, you're half right. It needs to be specified in the relationship explicitly unless it has been named using standard conventions.

Comment: @JoelHinz I think what he meant was that in his `User::find()`, he added a `select()` which did not include the `user_status_id` field. Without the foreign key field selected, Laravel can't do it's magic to connect the related models.

Comment: @patricus That's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, to lazy load any relationship, the foreign key value needs to be stored in the model object.

In my find operation, I wasn't querying the `user_status_id` field. When I added this field into the query, the `$user->status` statement started to return the `UserStatus` model.

I don't think this information is written on the Laravel docs, it may be simple, but it took me some time to figure that out.

Comment: I do not understand what you meant by this..What do you mean by the FK needs to be stored in the model object? Can you show us your complete code?

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower I don't have the code anymore since it's almost two years since I've opened this topic, apologies. What I mean is that you can't lazy load a relationship without having the referenced "id" loaded in your model. In my case, I was trying to do `$user->status()` without having the actual `user_status_id` in the object. It was sorted out once I filled the object with the `user_status_id`.

Answer (score 3):

in status() relation replace the line with

```
return $this->belongsTo('\App\UserStatus', 'user_status_id');
```

in user() relation with this

```
return $this->hasMany('\App\User', 'user_status_id');
```

Long story short add a '\' before App and remove third parameter since it is not many-to-many relationship.

Also make sure that you actually use Eloquent so add on top of models

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MODELNAME extends Model
```

and assign a table

```
protected $table = 'model_table';
```

Comment: You don't need the starting `\\` in those strings. Also every relationship method has extra parameters for overriding keys, not just belongsToMany.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Psy Shell to run it. For the first argument in belongsTo(), that could just be Classname::class. I encountered the case that I cannot perform belongsTo(), but if you restart your Psy Shell, it worked. It is weird though.